# audio preloader Jquery 

Tags: jquery, html

I am using html5-preloader to preload my audio files. It works fine in all browsers and android, but not in iPad. What is wrong with this code,

> http://code.google.com/p/html5-preloader/

```
    <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    var myLoader;
    myLoader = new html5Preloader();
    myLoader.loadFiles('assets/audio/aaa.mp3','assets/audio/bbb.mp3','assets/audio/ccc.mp3','assets/audio/ddd.mp3','assets/audio/eee.mp3');

    myLoader.onfinish = function(){alert('Done')};

    myLoader.on('finish',function(){ 
    alert("Done");
        document.getElementById("loading_layer").style.visibility = "hidden";
    });

    myLoader.onerror = function(e){alert('Error occured while loading '+this.loadingFile); retu

rn true; };

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i presume Safari on iOS?
looking at http://mobilehtml5.org/ it seems you need version 6.0 (of Safari, I presume) for audio tags to work. Is that the case?

Also, the preloader seems to have moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/html5Preloader.js).